# The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested

Tags: php, curl, header, request

I send this request by php curl

```
    $message_data=[
        "sendProjectMessageProjectThreadId"=>"102915g147219p133027",
        "sendProjectMessageText"=>"test message"

    ];
    $data=$this->get_content($this->url_message,$message_data);
 public function get_content($url,$data=[]){

        $data_string = json_encode($data);
 $delimiter = '-------------'.uniqid();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,__DIR__.'/cookie_message.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;  boundary='. $delimiter,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
         'Content-Length: ' .strlen($data_string)
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        return $result;


    }
```

And receive an error: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Please take a look how I get Request Payloads in original request http://prntscr.com/kv0wjr

And Now I get this error http://prntscr.com/kv5ezc

Comment: Content-Disposition is not a request header, and "form-data" is not a valid value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Please tell me in the code how I need to note this content disposition

Comment: I had trying this $data = ["json\";\nContent-type:\"application/json\";\nContent-disposition:\"form-data" => '{"sendProjectMessageProjectThreadId":"102915g147219p133027","sendProjectMessageText":"test message"}']; But have no success also

Comment: Now I get an error Required request part &#39;SendProjectMessageDto&#39; is not present